# java.io.IOException: Permission denied Save Bitmap image on sdcard

Tags: android, file, bitmap, save, sd-card

I try to save bitmap image on sdcard but show permission exception.

sdcard permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Horoscope/IMG_1569837709260.png (Permission denied)
```

my save bitmap method

```
public static void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, Activity activity) {
        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Horoscope");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        String fname = "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(activity.getContentResolver(), file.getPath(), fname, "description");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

error exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Horoscope/IMG_1569837709260.png (Permission denied)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
            at com.example.opencv.utils.Constant.saveImage(Constant.java:378)
            at com.example.opencv.activity.ForeignerMakerResultActivity$3.onClick(ForeignerMakerResultActivity.java:106)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6319)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24955)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

Comment: Have you requested the permissions? It seems like you have just written the permission in but you have not requested the permissions. Just request the permission and after the user grants the permissions save your bitmap

Comment: You need to request "runtime permission" for dangerous permission such as SD card. Please see the link I commented.

Comment: You can use below repo for runtime permission using annotations.
https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher

Answer (score 3):

**You must check and grant storage permission at tun time.**

Along with that you need add below code for SDK version >23

Extend *Application* class and inside onCreate() method put below code

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        builder.detectFileUriExposure();
    }
```

In Manifest.xml set **android:name**  value to your application class.

It would be like,

```
<application
    android:name="com.gym.client.WebURLApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to request permission on Activity

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

You also should check the mkdirs result as well to catch error like this

```
 if (myDir.mkdirs()) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are critical permissions, You have to check the permissions in runtime after you declared them in `manifest`.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is granted
}
else {
    //Permission is not granted so you have to request it
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
}
```